# Log4net doesn't work in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm very frustrated in making log4net in my windows service.
I've tried searching on Google but no solution solves my problems.

Here is my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
             type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" />    
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ApplicationSettings" value="Configurations/ApplicationSettings.json" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>

  <!-- log4net rolling file configuration -->
  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>

  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In program.cs at Main function, I tried calling:

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

In OnStart function of Main.cs (my service), I tried:

```
_log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Main));
_log.Error("Service started");
```

But nothing happens, log file doesn't appear when I write log.

Can anyone help me please?

I spent my whole day searching for solution but found nothing.

Thank you,

Comment: What account are you running the service in?  Does the account have **write** access to the folder where you intend to log to?

Comment: I set the ProjectInstaller to be LocalSystem.

Comment: Just not being able to find the file back would be the most common mishap.  It is not exactly healthy to write log files in the operating system directories, and the last place you'd look.  You did not specify a path for the file, so it is written to the default working directory of the program.  Which, for a service, is c:\windows\system32 or c:\windows\syswow64

Comment: I've search in these directories, I couldn't see my service there, even it was operating.

Comment: Since you have enabled log4net debugging, what does it show? (If you can't see the output, download dbgview from sysinternals and enable 'Capture Global Win32' and restart your service).

Comment: It doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a config issue above:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender"

<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
```

The names above have to match.  So both have to be set to `RollingFileAppender` for example.

Also when it comes to writing log files I tend not to try and write my log files anywhere in the program files directory or anything in any virtual directory just because of the previous battles I've had with security issues.  Currently I'm using something like the following for all my log4net log files:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/<Product Name>/Logs/<Program Name>/<Program Name>.log" />
```

`${ALLUSERSPROFILE}` is the key above.  This directory typically doesn't have the security restrictions as virtual directory and the program files directory.  I've found that I haven't had any trouble since I've been using this path.

This envrionment variable takes you to the `ProgramData` directory in Windows Vista, 7, 8, Server 2008 etc.  I think XP takes you to a different place but still a directory with relaxed permissions.  All you have to do is type in %allusersprofile% in file explorer and it will take you there.